# While Loop Result in On Window

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, c#-4.0

When I execute this stored procedure, it will return 5 windows, but I want to get this in a single window without converting it to string query.

I just post simplified version of query. i have different variable and logic here that every time change. So through loop i managed this and load resulted query into dataset in C# and current i get multiple dataset in code and merge that datatables. Even number of loops not limited to 5 times it will different every time according to user selection on web page view. I just want to get While loop result in single table without converting it into string query. Please guide me if you have any solution.

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT, @str VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @intFlag = 1

WHILE (@intFlag <= 5)

BEGIN

    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1

--Complex logical queries here that change every time according to 

    SELECT * FROM userHistories
END

GO
```

requirement[image].

Comment: insert into a table variable in the loop then select once on that table outside the loop

Comment: SQL you must use a OrderBy to get the same results every time.  SQL uses Asynchonous parallel searches to query the database and you do not get the same results in the same order every time.  So OrderBy Date in Decreasing Order and then take the 5 first five results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get it into one output if all the result columns are the same. If you're getting different results from your different logic each time, then you need to change those (by adding the missing columns as default values or null) so all the results are the same. Any time you add a new column to any of the queries, it has to be matched in all of them.

Then you have two options. If you have a preset, unchanging number or queries to run you may be able to do something like

```
Select query 1
UNION ALL Select query 2
UNION ALL Select query 3
```

This will return one result set, but it may be too simple for what you want. The other option is to create a temp table or a table variable, then change each of the queries you runt to insert their data to that table. Finally select the whole table to return the data to you at the end. It would look something like this (using a table variable)

```
Declare @Results TABLE (field1 int, field2 string ....)

While ... BEGIN
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    INSERT INTO @Results (field1, field2, ....)
    Select field1, field2 .... FROM ....

End
--Now return all the data
Select * from @Results
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, I would use a temp table to store the results of each of the queries generated within the while loop. You could even use the incrementing value in the temp table so that you could more easily identify which query the results came from. You really didn't supply enough details as to what the possibilities are within the while loop so I am making an assumption that the data is at least coming out with the same number of columns and/or data typing.

Additional information might provide better answers but that is what I would do based on your described need.